# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The NIB data is invalid.' after updating xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

I recently upgraded my xcode 4.2 to xcode 5. Now when I try to run my app on a iOS 5 device the exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The NIB data is invalid.' comes.

1. I have already  Unchecked the "use Autolayout" option in the storyboard.
2. I installed iOS 5 and iOS 5.1 SDKs and copied them to the xcode(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDK) and set the base SDK of my app to iOS 5.1 and 5.0. But still the exception is occurring. 
   What is the reason for this and what is the slution?
   Also the app works well in iOS6 and iOS7 simulators.

Comment: Seem to the particular NIB in not found. Can you conform the nib is properly rooted with the class?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change athe architecture . iOS 5 will not have support for  armv7 and armv7s

Follow my step

```
Click at Standard (armv7) $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)
Choose "Other"
CLick at "$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)" and the Click "-" to delete it
Click "+" to add new item
Type "armv6"
Click "+" again
Type "armv7"
Click anywhere to finish
```

I hope this help

I just have the same problem and I try to do this and it work for me

Comment: hi, I tried your steps. But it did not work. still, the same exception comes.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this screen shots it may help:

Step 1 :

[image]

Step 2:

[image]